# VBA: range defined by a fixed cell and an active cell

Tags: excel, vba, range

I'm trying to use a macro to format data as a table. It needs to work regardless of the number of rows and columns occupied,

I've tried the following, which caused an error:

```
Sub Macro1()
Set **selectedCell** = Application.ActiveCell
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:**selectedCell**"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
    Cells.Select
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at `.CurrentRegion.Address`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select within your code

You can use `CurrentRegion` of `ActiveCell` - which already returns a range - so no need to use address as Nathan_sav suggested.

Furthermore `ListObjects.Add` returns a `ListObject` - you can use that to set the other properties.

```vb
Dim lo As ListObject
Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, , xlYes)

With lo
    .Name = "Table1"
    .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight8"
End With
```